# Android Нажатие на кнопку - переворачивает картинку

Tags: android, android-fragment, textview, rotation

Есть `Fragment` в которой есть `TextView`, нужно чтобы по нажатию на `TextView` картинка с права от текста поворачивалась на 45° градусов, и при следующем нажатии возвращалась в исходную позицию. Как это сделать?

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/color_1"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow"
            android:background="@color/color_3"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/color_5"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView_5"
                android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Java

```
public class ItemFiveFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private View linear_layout;

    public static ItemFiveFragment newInstance() {
        return new ItemFiveFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_setting, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        linear_layout = requireView().findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

        View text_view = requireView().findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        text_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (linear_layout.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                {
                    linear_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    linear_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте анимацию вроде такого. Только вам придется написать 2 анимации одну для поворота, вторую для возврата в исходное состояние. И в вашем clickListener-e их чередовать.

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 45, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotate.setDuration(300); rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); 
ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
image.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: а как их чередовать в clickListener-e?

Comment: Можете флаг сделать и в зависимости от него вызывать разную анимацию.